# Find this derivative

Tags: calculus

assume $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and let $$
y(x)=\int_0^x\left(f(t)+\left(\int_0^xf(t)+\left(\int_0^xf(t)+...\right)\right)\right)dt.
$$ Find $y'(x)$.

Note $$y(x)=\int_0^x\left(f(t)+y(x)\right)dt=xy(x)+\int_0^xf(t)dt$$ so $y'(x)=y(x)+f(x)$. Does this look correct?

Comment: Starting from $y(x)=xy(x)+\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$ if you apply $d/dx$ to both sides: $y'(x)=y(x)+xy'(x)+f(x)$ where I think you neglected the product rule on $xy(x)$. This leads to $y'(x)=\frac{y(x)+f(x)}{1-x}$

Comment: @alex.jordan yes, you're right

Comment: There is a question of whether this expression makes any sense in the first place. Suppose $f$ is a constant function. Then it is easy to show $y(1)$ makes no sense (does not converge). I don't immediately see what conditions on $f$ or $x$ guarantee convergence.